# why should there be a limit on length of JSON while sending serialized data from any browser?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I've been programming web applications for a while now,many a times i get to use JQuery AJAX and webmethods to pass data back and forth.But somehow i forget to set the "MaxJsonLength" property until the browser hit me back with an exception.

I don't understand why can't the browsers just allow any lengths of JSON strings by default rather than posing an exception and failing the "AJAX post".

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but I imagine it's a combination of limiting memory usage, and security.

Comment: To answer your specific question: the browser doesn't have any limitation.  Your web application is where you apply the setting.  For a public facing site that only needs a few kb per post, you'll be opening yourself up to DoS attacks as hackers post *Gbs* to your server - better to stop it sooner.   Setting up a site doesn't know if it's going to be internal or external, so errs on the side of caution.